# SQL Joining Values to A Set Of Values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Say I have two tables: 
Table 1:

```
number
1
2
3
```

and Table 2:

```
letter
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
```

how can i produce

```
number      letter
a              1
a              2
a              3
b              1
b              2
b              3
c              1
c              2
c              3
```

all the way to g - i would just like to assign one of each value to each specific value of a table

Comment: Try googling CROSS JOIN

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While the query suggested like:

```
SELECT number, letter FROM Table1, Table2
```

will work the same, and even might look simpler - [DON'T USE IT.](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) It is an old style syntax outdated more then 20 years ago with the introduction of ANSI-92 standards.

Please use ANSI-JOINS:

```
SELECT t1.number, t2.letter
FROM Table1 t1
CROSS JOIN Table2 t2
```

Also get in the habit to always alias and prefix your columns.

Answer (score 5):

Cross join:

```
select Table1.number, Table2.letter 
from Table1 CROSS JOIN Table2
```

Comment: Using `,` in this way is deprecated.  Why suggest this instead of ANSI JOINs?

Comment: @MatBailie because I didn't know that it was deprecated! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

to get what you're looking for, do this:

```
select letter,number 
from Table2 cross join Table1 
order by letter,number
```

Comment: Very poor programming technique.

Comment: hmmm ... I don't see why